# How to insert PHP value in jQuery Datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I have the following code to set the minimum date of datepicker.

```
$( "#sd" ).datepicker({
    // before datepicker opens run this function
    beforeShow: function(){
        // this gets today's date       
        var theDate = new Date();
        // sets "theDate" 2 days ahead of today
        theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate() + 2);
        // set min date as 2 days from today
        $(this).datepicker('option','minDate',theDate);         
    },
    // When datepicker for start date closes run this function
    onClose: function(){
        // this gets the selected start date        
        var theDate = new Date($(this).datepicker('getDate'));
        // this sets "theDate" 1 day forward of start date
        theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate() + 1);
        // set min date for the end date as one day after start date
        $('#ed').datepicker('option','minDate',theDate);

    }
});
```

If today's date is 11/14/2012 then the value of datepicker is 11/16/2012. However, since the date should be based on server's datetime I cannot use javascript date because it will get the current date of the computer instead of server's date.

So what I did is change it to the following code:

```
$( "#sd" ).datepicker({
    // before datepicker opens run this function
    beforeShow: function(){
        // this gets today's date       
        var theDate = new Date();
        // sets "theDate" 2 days ahead of today
        //theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate() + 2);
        theDate.setDate(<?php echo $this->session->userdata('checkin') ?>);
        // set min date as 2 days from today
        $(this).datepicker('option','minDate',theDate);         
    },
    // When datepicker for start date closes run this function
    onClose: function(){
        // this gets the selected start date        
        var theDate = new Date($(this).datepicker('getDate'));
        // this sets "theDate" 1 day forward of start date
        theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate() + 1);
        // set min date for the end date as one day after start date
        $('#ed').datepicker('option','minDate',theDate);

    }
});
```

Please take a look at this line:

```
theDate.setDate(<?php echo $this->session->userdata('checkin') ?>);
```

BTW, I am using codeigniter session.

This works great but the problem is the minimum date in datepicker is not set to 11/16/2012 instead it was set to 11/2/2012.

Anyone know how to insert the PHP value correctly into jQuery?

Comment: You're sure the value of $this->session->userdata('checkin') isn't actually 11/2/2012..??

Comment: I am sure the value is 11/16/2012..

Comment: Based on what you're showing here that just doesn't seem to be the case.  You're simply echoing that value, and you're getting a value, so that must be the value stored in that session variable from what I'm seeing.

What if you dump the entire session array to the screen at this point?  What do you get then?

Comment: seems that if you worked with UTC dates on both ends would help

Answer (score 0):

I have already found the answer. Here it is:

```
$( "#sd" ).datepicker({
    // before datepicker opens run this function
    beforeShow: function(){
        // this gets today's date       
        var theDate = new Date();
        theDate.setDate(<?php echo date('d', strtotime($this->session->userdata('checkin'))) ?>);
        // set min date as 2 days from today
        $(this).datepicker('option','minDate',theDate);         
    },
    // When datepicker for start date closes run this function
    onClose: function(){
        // this gets the selected start date        
        var theDate = new Date($(this).datepicker('getDate'));
        // this sets "theDate" 1 day forward of start date
        theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate() + 1);
        // set min date for the end date as one day after start date
        $('#ed').datepicker('option','minDate',theDate);

    }
});
```

It should extract the day only and not the whole date.

```
theDate.setDate(<?php echo date('d', strtotime($this->session->userdata('checkin'))) ?>);
```

Instead of

```
theDate.setDate(<?php echo $this->session->userdata('checkin') ?>);
```